# python vowels to lowercase and consonants to uppercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase, lowercase

I'm new to python and I'm stuck on this particular exercise.
I'm trying to make a program to take an input from the user (a string) and switch all the vowels to lowercase and consonants to uppercase.

Example input: `"Learning python is fun."`
Expected output: `"LeaRNiNG PYTHoN iS FuN."`

This is what I've tried:

```
def toggle(phrase):
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter not in "aeiou":
            letter = letter.upper()
        elif letter in "AEIOU":
            letter = letter.lower()
        else:
            letter = letter.upper()
    return phrase


print(toggle(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

However, the output is not toggling anything. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see where you ever changed phrase itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say `letter = letter.upper`, you're not actually changing the contents of the string `phrase`, you're just changing the string that the variable `letter` points to.

In fact, you can't mutate strings in python. Try running `"hello"[0] = "g"` and you'll get an error.

One solution is instead of trying to modify the string `phrase`, we can build a new string and put the correct letters in it. Here's what I mean:

```py
def toggle(phrase):
    answer = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter not in "aeiouAEIOU":
            answer = answer + letter.upper()
        else:
            answer = answer + letter.lower()
    return answer


print(toggle(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

when you run this, you get

```
Enter a phrase: Learning python is fun.
LeaRNiNG PYTHoN iS FuN.
```

It might look like I'm mutating the string when I say `answer = answer + letter.upper()`, but what actually happens is that, similar to what you did with letter, I'm not actually changing a string itself, I'm just making a new string (`answer + letter.upper()`) and assigning the value of that string to the variable `answer`. That's a subtle, but important difference.

I also changed the way you decided whether to do uppercase or lowercase to make it work for lowercase vowels. The way you had it originally, if the current letter is `"a"`, the else branch runs and it gets uppercased when it shouldn't. This is because `"a"` is in `"aeiou"` and it's not in `"AEIOU"`, so the else branch runs and it gets uppercased.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you're looping over an iterable of the phrase and by assigning letter you aren't actually changing the letters in phrase.

You could turn the whole string to upper then use `str.translate`

```
vowel_trans = str.maketrans('AEIOU', 'aeiou')
def toggle(phrase):
    return phrase.upper().translate(vowel_trans)
```

In the case this will not suffice you can generate a string while looping using the same logic and return that string.

```
def toggle(phrase):
    new_phrase = ''
    for letter in phrase.upper():
        if letter in 'AEIOU':
            new_phrase += letter.lower()
        else:
            new_phrase += letter
```

**EDIT**

This can be shortened to a comprehension as well:

```
def toggle(phrase):
    return ''.join(l.lower() if l in 'AEIOU' else l for letter in phrase)
```

Or even done using `re`:

```
import re

def toggle(phrase):
    return re.sub('AEIOU', 'aeiou', phrase.upper())
```

Comment: Note: If you expect to do this a lot, it would be better to call and store the result of `maketrans` once, outside the function, in a global, to avoid the cost of recreating the translation dictionary (which is unchanging) on every call.

Comment: Absolutely, didn't even cross my mind nice observation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to say "All the vowels are lowercase and all the consonants are uppercase"

```
def toggle(phrase):
    new_phrase = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] or letter in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
            new_phrase += letter.lower()
        else:
            new_phrase += letter.upper()
    return new_phrase


print(toggle(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

Comment: You could easily have kept the form of the OP's test (which is more efficient in scanning a string rather than a `list` of strings). If you want to make it simpler, simply doing `if letter in 'aeiouAEIOU':` or `if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':` would be much shorter and faster to boot.

Comment: You can't actually only scan only 'aeiou', because then the code would go to the else line and the letter would then be in the uppercase.

Comment: Reread what I typed; the second version calls `.lower()` so it only needs to check `'aeiou'`.

Answer (score 0):

def convert_consonants_to_uppercase(phrase):
result = ""
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

```
for char in phrase:
    if char.isalpha():
        if char.lower() not in vowels:
            result += char.upper()
        else:
            result += char.lower()
    else:
        result += char

return result
```

## Input a phrase from the user

input_phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")

## Call the function to perform the conversion

converted_phrase = convert_consonants_to_uppercase(input_phrase)

## Display the converted phrase

print("Converted phrase:", converted_phrase)